# html, css, javascript - ebook (text) reader

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

I'm a newbie so be kind to me :)

I have a large text that I'm trying to present in html, I want the text to 'fill the screen's real-estate' depending on the browser/device - mobile vs desktop - if its going overboard then I want it to trunk the remaining text and present it in another html (i.e. next page). I've tried searching for pagination and whatnot, I'm using html,css,javascript.. and pretty new to all this :)

I do understand my question is probably vague, but even a small direction would help so much!

(Just to make things clearer, I'm trying to build a javascript ebook reader that I can add public domain books in the future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you have to do.

1. Figure out a way to see if text is overflowing
2. Chop off excess text
3. Make a link that fills the content div with the leftover text
4. Repeat recursively
5. If you don't know what recursion is goto step 5 else +1

Comment: @Shay: you must not have followed step 5

Answer (score 1):

I think you are much better to just set the pages to a reasonable size with some white space at the top and bottom, then let users scroll, pan and zoom as they like. Some like to scroll so that the line they are reading is always near the top, others in the middle.

There is also a big difference in the number of lines displayed in portrait and landscape modes.

If presented in normal page size chunks in plain HTML, you don't need any script at all and your readers can control scrolling, zoom and orientation in the manner that suits them best.

Comment: I want to create an ebook experience on the iPhone. I think it'll be more convenient for the user if they could scroll through pages instead of some arbitrary size text. They'll be able to bookmark the pages..

Comment: @Shay - the text size isn't arbitrary, users have control over the default and minimum size of text in browsers. Just leave it to its default size and users will be happy, though you might offer a choice of serif or sans-serif font.